# Issue Symfony 3 // Ajax Method Post

Tags: php, ajax, google-maps, symfony

I am currently working on a personal project with Symfony 3 and I have some issues with AJAX Post method to send data through Doctrine.
To be more specific, my project consists on displaying markers on a Google Maps and a input text on which people can put marker's address (thanks to Google autocomplete). So I would like to stock name's address, latitude and longitude in my DB.
My problem appears on the Controller which sends data to my DB. I don't know where to put the json_encode.

Anyone can help me please ?

In my view :

```
$('#envoi').on('click', onSubmit);

function onSubmit(){
var data = {
 "address":$("#form_address").val(),
 "lat":lat,
 "lng":lng,
 "dateconcert":  $("#form_dateconcert").val(),
 "timeconcert":  $("#form_timeconcert").val(),
 "descconcert": $("#form_concertdescription").val()
 }
$.post('{{ path('setevent') }}', data, onReturn);
 }

function onReturn(serverResponse){
window.location = '{{ path('setevent') }}';
}
```

In my Controller :

```
use AppBundle\Entity\Event;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TimeType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;

class EventCreationController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/profile/setevent", name="setevent")
*/
 public function new(Request $request)
{
$event = new Event();

$event->setDateconcert(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($event)
     ->add('address', TextType::class, array('label' => "L'adresse de l'évènement : "))
    ->add('dateconcert', DateType::class, array('label' => "Sélectionnez la date de votre évènement : ",
    'widget' => 'single_text'))
    ->add('timeconcert', TimeType::class, array('label' => "Sélectionnez l'heure de votre évènement : ",
        'widget' => 'single_text'))
    ->add('concertdescription', TextType::class, array('label' => "Décrivez votre évènement"))
    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => "C'est parti !",
    'attr'=> array('class'=>'send')))
    ->getForm();

return $this->render('creationevent/creationevent.html.twig', array(
'form' => $form->createView(),
));
}
}
```

With this, I don't have any errors. So far, I don't know where to put the Doctrine's instructions and the json_encode of these to send data to my DB.

Comment: Could you include what you tried so far along with possible errors message in your post? As it is there is not much we can do to help

Comment: @Theo: Please edit your question and insert the code there. Do NOT post additional information as answer, because this is not how Stack Overflow works. Besides, other users will skip your question because they’ll think that the question is already answered.

Comment: @lxg Ok. Thanks. It's my first question on Stack Overflow. I didn't know that.

Comment: @Theo "_It's my first question on Stack Overflow. I didn't know that._" before to post your next question take some time to read the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), where you will find all the necessary infos to create nice, useful and on-topic questions = fast and concrete help but without any time loss due to the lacks of information related to the question.

Comment: @Theo: You say you don’t have any errors. What is your problem then? Did you try putting the DB interaction code into the controller? Did it work for you? If not, did you get an error message or any other indicator of what might have gone wrong?